# Add constant number of days only to specific values of a data frame containing dates

Tags: r, date, dataframe

I have a data.frame FYE containing dates with I compare with an other data.frame containing dates DATES. Dimensions of both a the same. I then define a logical matrix `A <- matrix(FYE < DATES, nrow = nrow(FYE), ncol = ncol(FYE))`. For each cell in A with equals TRUE I want to add 365 days to the corresponding value in FYE. I tried the following, but it didn't work:

```
  A <- matrix(FYE < DATES, nrow = nrow(FYE),
                ncol = ncol(FYE))

  FYE[A == TRUE] <- FYE + 365
```

The error code is:

```
Error in date_next_FYE[A == TRUE] + 365 : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Create some data

```
dates <- seq(as.Date("2016-01-01"), as.Date("2017-06-05"), by="day")
set.seed(1234)
FYE <- data.frame(d1=sample(dates, 20), d2=sample(dates, 20), d3=sample(dates, 20))
DATES <- data.frame(d1=sample(dates, 20), d2=sample(dates, 20), d3=sample(dates, 20))
```

Now, see what the subsetting does

```
str(FYE[FYE < DATES])
chr [1:22] "2016-02-29" "2016-11-27" "2016-01-05" "2016-04-29"
```

This is an odd result. It appears that subsetting `FYE[FYE < DATES]` returns a character string. This extraction removes the date class, so you have to add it back on with `as.Date`.

So

```
FYE[FYE < DATES] <- as.Date(FYE[FYE < DATES]) + 365
```

will work as desired.

We can check that changes have been made. Starting with original data above,

```
sum(FYE < DATES)
[1] 22

FYE[FYE < DATES] <- as.Date(FYE[FYE < DATES]) + 365

sum(FYE < DATES)
[1] 4
```

Maybe one more time, for good measure:

```
FYE[FYE < DATES] <- as.Date(FYE[FYE < DATES]) + 365
sum(FYE < DATES)
[1] 0
```

Comment: So the class is removed because it extracts them as (dimensionless) vectors?

Comment: This was a surprise to me, but for the subsetting `FYE[FYE < DATES]`, `FYE < DATES` returns a logical matrix, and the entire expression returns a vector of class character, stripping the class attribute. I guess this makes sense. Since with the matrix subsetting, R is extracting from multiple list elements and is not sure if they are all of the same data type, probably safest to convert to the most general data type (here character) in order to preserve to information?

Comment: That makes sense. Matrices can not hold dates I think, so the logical matrix is indeed what breaks the class (most probably)

Comment: Aha. That's it. The matrix class overides the Date class. `matrix(sample(dates, 20), 5)` from the example data above returns a matrix of doubles.

Comment: @lmo, thanks. But somehow, it still does not work with my actual data. Might the reason be that it has NAs?

Comment: If that is the case, change `FYE < DATES` to `FYE < DATES & !is.na(FYE) & !is.na(DATES)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 library(lubridate)

 ymd("2016-07-01") + days(365)
```